# Dynamic size of footer with full screen web page

Tags: html, css, sass

[image wireframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0y5j.png)

I would like to recreate messaging phone app in html and css. So the app must be full frame without any overflow.
The trick is the bottom part (in red) must be resizable according to the child content. So I used flex (with flex-direction: column) to manage my layout.

The problem is : when the content (in yellow) grow up, the core part will compress the red part. My goal is to overflow, with a scrollbar, the content inside the core part and don't change the size of the red div.

*index.html*

```
<body>
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="core">
    <div class="conainer" style="">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="two columns"></div>
            <div class="ten columns">
                <div class="msgright">
                    .
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="ten columns">
                <div class="msgright">
                    .
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="two columns"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
```

*index.css*

```
html, body, div {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#header {
    height: 50px;
    background: #2A9D8F;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

#core {
    background-color: #264653;
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

#footer {
    height: auto;
    background-color: red;
    min-height: 50px;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.conainer {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
}

.row {
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 130px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/jln_brtn/pen/pobVZBv

Best regards and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is just the `#core` element, then you can do something like this:

```
#core {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand the problem correctly but since your `.row` elements have a fixed `height: 130px`, the element should not be able to grow any further. Overflow styling to `.row` elements can be added like this:

```
.row {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this instance I would suggest to use CSS Grid instead of Flexbox, and giving both `<header>` and `<footer>` the space they need, while the `<main>` gets the rest. This means that both `<header>` and `<footer>` stay were they are, even if `<main>` needs more space for its content, meaning `<main>` will get a scrollbar.

You can achieve the same by using `position: fixed` and setting a margin to top and bottom, with fixed heights of `<header>` and `<footer>`, and sizing `<main>` with `height: calc(100% - HEIGHT_OF_HEADER - HEIGHT_OF_FOOTER)`. The problem with this is maintenance, as you would always have to check and revalidate the heights when changing something.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}

header {
  height: 3.125rem;
  background: #2A9D8F;
}
main {
  padding: 0.3125rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  gap: 0.3125rem;
  background: #264653;
  overflow: hidden auto;
}
footer {
  height: 3.125rem;
  background: red;
}

main > div {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 8.125rem;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</main>
<footer></footer>
```